# Chunk-vendors files is too big on production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

After production build my vue.js app, i saw that my chunk-vendors files are too big and this have an impact on web performance, screen below:

[image]

how to reduce size of this files?

I try to import component in my router.js via lazy loading but not help here, what is another solution to this problem?

thanks for any help!

Comment: These are all of your `node_modules` which are notorious for being a blackhole. To reduce size you need to reduce dependencies in your `node_modules`

Comment: As maxshuty already wrote, you should make sure to use less node_modules. You can achieve this by reducing your `package.json` to the most essential. What you are experiencing is called **dependency hell**. you can read about it here: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) or [here](https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/04/09/ride-down-the-javascript-dependency-hell.html)

Answer (score 2):

Further to the previous comments, you likely need to analyse what is being imported into your app.

A good way to do this is through a dependency analysis. If you're using vue-cli, you can add [Webpack Bundle Analysis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyzer) to your devDependencies. This will allow you to see what is being imported.

Pay special attention to things like icon libraries (like @mdi) and other helper libraries like @vueuse or lodash. If they're imported incorrectly, you can end up with the entire package rather than treeshaking out only the ones used.